# React Select, how to change the font size on on the dropdown menu

Tags: reactjs, select

React Select, how to change the font size on  on the dropdown menu

```js
 const customStyles = {
    control: (base) => ({
      ...base,
      fontSize: 13,
      paddingTop: 3,
    }),
  };
```

Comment: You should just need to change the font size from an integer to a string '13px'

Comment: It doesn't let me do 13px , just 13

Answer (score 3):

You almost got it correct. Just change the `fontSize` int 13 to string `'13px'`/`'13em'`. This will change the font size of the option selected.

To change the font size of the menu option, add the below code in `customStyles`:

```
menuPortal: base => ({
            ...base,
            fontSize: '13px'
        }),
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass styles directly as props to react-select(hoping you're talking about the same)

```
<Select
  styles={{ menuPortal: (base) => ({ ...base, zIndex: 9999 }) }}
  menuPortalTarget={document.body}
  isSearchable
  name="color"
  menuPlacement={menuPlacement}
  options={colourOptions}
  menuShouldScrollIntoView={false}
/>
```

For more help, you could also refer to the advanced docs in react-select
https://react-select.com/advanced#portaling